# Triple modular redundancy (TMR) in hardware

Tags: fpga, asic, fault

I would like to know if there are already ASICs/FPGAs implemented on top triple modular redundancy for fault tolerance/if they themselves implement TMR for fault correction. Any reference to research paper describing such implementation would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

ASICs are custom, so you can do what you want. Some FPGAs and CPLDS have built in "rad-hard" (RADiation-HARDened) versions that resist the errors rather than have fault tolerance.

But most FPGAs don't have that feature. On the last space FPGAs I worked on had 3 big FPGAs (Xilinx) for redundancy. A small rad-hard Actel FPGA to perform the  TMR comparison.

Xilinx does have [a tool for adding TMR](http://www.xilinx.com/ise/optional_prod/tmrtool.htm) within certain FPGAs.